# present perfect with "for": For almost a century, researchers have argued over this question

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

How do the meanings of the following sentences differ:

1. For almost a century, researchers have argued over this question.
2. For almost a century, researchers have been arguing over this question.

I understand that the present perfect continuous tense emphasizes that the action is continuing while the present perfect tense do the result. What baffles me is the use of latter with "for almost a century", which seems to go with the former better, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Even the present perfect tense can be used for continuous actions upto the present moment.It may have two meanings.

I have lived in the house for a year. It may mean that you are still living in the house or recently vacated it.

> **For almost a century,researchers have argued over this**

This may not mean that they stopped arguing over this question.

> **For almost a century, researchers have been arguing over this question**

This is very clear and means researchers are arguing even now.

But both the sentences are correct.